# How do I use Shared Data in UWP

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app

I tried to load a data from a json file in the local folder and it works fine in PC cause the data was kept in the LocalState folder in PC but when I try to use it in phone it says that the data is not in the phone. Where should I keep the json file so that it is accessible by both phone and PC? It's a UWP app.

Comment: Take a look at *roaming data*.

Answer (score 0):

Like Romasz said, use [Roaming data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx) for shared data if you not require instant sync and 100% data consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use roaming data to store shared user data between devices of one Microsoft account.
Here's some code you can refer:

```
ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
StorageFolder roamingFolder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
//Get from roaming settings
object userName = roamingSettings.Values["UserName"];
if (userName != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName.ToString()))
{
    ViewModel.UserName = userName.ToString();
}
//Set to roaming settings
roamingSettings.Values["UserName"] = ViewModel.UserName;
//You can also save the info into a file.
StorageFile processFile = await roamingFolder.CreateFileAsync(processFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(processFile, ViewModel.GameProcess.ToString());

//Get from the file
try
{
    StorageFile processFile = await roamingFolder.GetFileAsync(processFileName);
    string process = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(processFile);
    int gameProcess;
    if (process != null && int.TryParse(process.ToString(), out gameProcess) && gameProcess > 0)
    {
        ViewModel.GameProcess = gameProcess;
    }
}
catch { }
```

To get the full project, go to [Sample:How to share data across multiple devices in Win10 UWP App](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-share-data-across-d492cc0b).